# do i need to create a route for each page ? (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, routes, view

in node.js, lets say for example i have 5 somename.js files in my route dir
and in each one i have 5 exports.some_page_url method

so like this i have 25 routes in my app
do i need in my app.js to write 25 routes?
for example

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/p1', routes.page1);
app.get('/p2', routes.page2);
app.get('/p3', routes.page3);
app.get('/p4', routes.page4);
app.get('/p5', routes.page5);
app.get('/p6', routes.page6);
app.get('/p7', routes.page7);
app.get('/p8', routes.page8);
app.get('/p9', routes.page9);
...
```

index.js file

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
exports.page1 = function(req, res){
   //some methods
   res.render('page1', { title: 'Express' });
};
exports.page2 = function(req, res){
   //some methods
   res.render('page2', { title: 'Express' });
};
exports.page3 = function(req, res){
   //some methods
   res.render('page3', { title: 'Express' });
};
exports.page4 = function(req, res){
   //some methods
   res.render('page4', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

and of course each page has a different logic

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use routing system within express:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.get('/page/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('page' + req.params.id, { title: 'Express' });
});
```